# Differentiability of curve vs. linear approximation of curve's image set

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm currently trying to understand why in differential geometry it's usually required for a curve $c:I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to be regular, that is $\|c'(t)\| \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$. I was thinking about the image of the smooth curve $c: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $t \mapsto (\sin t,\; \sin t)$ and I think it shows that we need some extra conditions on $c$ other than being differentiable (this curve is not regular, of course). Wolfgang Kühnel motivates the requirement in his book "Differential Geometry: Curves - Surfaces - Manifolds" as follows:

> [...] Differentiability of a map just means that it can be linearly
>   approximated. For the image set, however, this no longer needs to be
>   the case. From a geometrical point of view it makes sense to require
>   that the image curve can be approximated by a line at each point,
>   i.e., to require that the image curve has a tangent as a geometrical
>   linearization at every point. This means that the derivative of c must
>   be non-vanishing.

This confuses me a lot. Where's the difference of linearly approximating $c$ or its image? Let's consider the case of *plane curves* for a moment. If $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ there exists a unique tangent at $x_0$. Visually, I'm thinking about the tangent at $(x_0, f(x_0))$ with respect to the graph $G_f = \{\;(x, f(x)\,)\;|\;x \in I\; \}$, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The graph of $f$ determines a regular plane curve, since $\|\frac{d}{dx} (x, f(x))\| = \sqrt{1 + f'(t)^2} \neq 0$. I don't really see in which way this fails if we have different coordinate functions.
Can someone please elaborate a bit on what Kühnel is talking about?

EDIT: To clarify a bit: As seen in Aaron's example, we can have curves that are smooth but also have a cusp (something a real-valued differentiable function of one variable cannot have). Thus it's only natural to seek for conditions that produce "well-behaved" curves. Apparently regularity is the property we're looking for in this case. The question is: WHY and HOW does $c'(t) \neq 0$ prevent this pathological behavior? What is the intuition behind this condition. It's easy to look at a curve like $c(t) = (t^3, t^2)$ and conclude that it is not regular at $t = 0$, but it's not as easy to understand why regularity alone prevents this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of regular curve seems off.

**Definition:**

> A differentiable curve $c : I \to \mathbb R^n$ is regular when $c'(t) \neq 0$ for every $t \in I$.

An example where this fails is the curve $c : I  \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $c(t) = (t^3,t^2)$. Then $c'(t) = (3t^2,2t)$ and $c'(0) = 0$ this curve is not regular and it looks like this

[image]

Roughly speaking, a regular curve doesn't have any pointy edges or unexpected bumps.

And perhaps the nature of your misunderstanding lies on distinguishing the trace of a curve with its graph. What is shown in the picture above is called the trace of $c$, that is, the image $c(I) \subset \mathbb R^2$. The graph of $c$ would be the collection of all pairs $(t,c(t))$ and therefore a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Aaron. You're correct; apparently the usual definition of a regular curve doesn't involve its norm. However, I don't think it makes a difference since for any norm $\|x\| = 0 \iff x = 0$. Your example shows that non-regular curves can have a cusp, which is something we'd like to avoid. If this was a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ I would suspect that it's not differentiable at the origin (in fact $f(x) = x^{2/3}$ is not diff. at $x=0$). The big question is: Why does the condition $c'(t) \neq 0$ prevent behaviour like this?

Comment: Oh, I forgot your last point. I understand the difference between trace of a curve and its graph. Admittedly my example was probably a bit misleading. I just wanted to show that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable then the curve corresponding to its graph is regular. However, most curves are much more complex. For example a graph cannot self-intersect. I just wanted to find a connection between the differentiability of a function and its image set as described by Kühnel. I wasn't really able to do it though.

Comment: You see, you will find more fruitful to understand differentiability over the trace, since the linear approximations are taken over there.

Comment: I guess you're right. Maybe there's nothing more to it other than that if $c'(t_0) = 0$ the tangent at $t = t_0$ defined as $T(\alpha) = c(t_0) + \alpha c'(t_0)$ equals $c(t_0)$ which doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 0):

Curves are taken to regular because we get nice forms for formulas when we can parametrize curves by arc-length. Recall that if $\gamma(t)$ is regular,then we can parametrize $\gamma$ with the unit-speed parameter $s$, $(\|\gamma'(s)\| = 1$ for all $s$).